# Kendo data source after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo data source that loads on document.ready() and populates a combobox with results from JSON request. Then once the user selects an item in the combobox I tell have a function customerSelected() execute to load the values for that customer. Problem I am having is I can't set another Kendo data source to populate with data after the page has loaded. If I use a regular Jquery ajax call the data seems to load in after Kendo templating executes and doesn't populate my data.

```
function customerSelected(customerid) {
    var customer = customerid;

    var commTemplate = kendo.template(' # for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { # <div class="communication" contentEditable>#= data[i].fname # - #= data[i].lname # #= data[i].details #</div> # } # ');
    var commData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "index.php?mode=showCustomerData",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#communications").html(commTemplate(commData));
}

$('document').ready(function() {

    var customers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "index.php?mode=showCustomers",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    });
    $("#customerBox").kendoComboBox({
        dataSource: customers,
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "customer_id",
        filter: "contains",
        change: function(e) {
            console.log(this.value());
            customerSelected(this.value());
            $("#customerSelected").val(this.value());

        }
    });


});
```

Every data source here returns correct JSON data that I have verified with a rest client. The problem is just that the kendo.data.DataSource() in the customerSelected() function doesn't actually do anything. I have tried a variety of ways to get this functionality that I am used to in the purely Jquery world of doing Ajax calls and appending/updating the DOM. What am I missing here to allow for another DataSource after the DOM has been loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are that:

1. You are not reading the data after creating the data source.
2. Data is loaded asynchronously, so you can't use it right away.

Try this:

```
function customerSelected(customerid) {
    var customer = customerid;

    var commTemplate = kendo.template(' # for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { # <div class="communication" contentEditable>#= data[i].fname # - #= data[i].lname # #= data[i].details #</div> # } # ');
    var commData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "index.php?mode=showCustomerData",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    });

    // run this callback the next time data changes
    // which will be when the data is done being read from the server
    commData.one("change", function () {
        $("#communications").html(commTemplate(commData.data()));
    });

    // read the data from the server
    commData.fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var commTemplate = kendo.template(' # for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { # <div class="communication" contentEditable>#= data[i].fname # - #= data[i].lname # #= data[i].details #</div> # } # ');
var commData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "index.php?mode=showCustomerData",
        dataType: "json"
    }
},
change: function() {
    $("#communications").html(kendo.render(commTemplate, this.view());
}
});

commData.read();
```

Taken from: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/remote-data.html

Comment: This was helpful but it doesn't populate the data. I see the DataSource actually does the request to the server now and chrome network developer tab shows the results: [{"id":"1","fname":"Keizer","lname":"Von","details":"THESE ARE SOME DETAILS"}] but the data doesn't get iterated on the page. I was able to get the templating engine to do iteration of data when I tried with jquery but the data fields didn't assign properly

Comment: Perhaps I need to define schema? console.log() reports  {"options":{"data":[],"schema":{},"serverSorting":false,"serverPaging":false,"serverFiltering":false,"serverGrouping":false,"serverAggregates":false,"batch":false,"transport":{"read":{"url":"index.php?mode=showCustomerData","dataType":"json"}}},"_map":{},"_prefetch":{},"_data":[],"_pristineData":[],"_ranges":[],"_view":[],"_pristine":[],"_destroyed":[],"_group":[],"_events":{"sync":[null]},"transport":{"options":{"read":{"url":"index.php?mode=showCustomerData","dataType":"json"}},"cache":{}},"reader":{},"_requestInProgress":true}

Comment: Further tinkering I was able to get data to iterate using this in the change: function() { $("#communications").html(commTemplate(this._pristine)); }

Answer (score 0):

$("#communications").html(commTemplate(this._pristine));

Comment: Adding an explanation about why this solves the question would help the OP learn.

Comment: This is more of a hack than adhering to the conventions of Kendo. Only reason it works is because I dumped the output of DataSource internally and found that this._pristine had the resulting data I was expecting. It should of been way more straight forward than this. The DataSource.data object wasn't being populated but DataSource._pristine was, which when searching Google I couldn't find anything related to _pristine

Comment: Taking a look into your original code it seems to me that the problem is that you try to populate the data just after defining the DataSource but it is not guaranteed that data is already received. Try adding a delay in your service (index.php) and see if this still runs... I would say that unless you run this code inside a callback that waits for the data from being received, it will fail. Unless that you want to depend on KendoUI internals and being exposed to future changes in the implementation: you should not use `_pristine` but `data()` method.